# shared_ptr and logical pointer ownership use-case in a complex design

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, shared-ptr, asynchronous

I have an Object `A` that contains a shared resource (shared_ptr) `r`, `A` is the creator/owner of `r` upon construction the object "registers" its `r` with another object B. Object B holds a reference to `A`'s `r` in a `std::set`. Object A is used as a Boost::asio::handler.

I need to unregister `r` from `B` when `A` is being destructed, and when `A` holds unique access to `r`, as `A` is `r`'s creator it is responsible for destroying it. Note: A is copy constructed multiple times when it is used as an [boost::asio handler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html). Holding unque acces here means that no asio operations are taking place (because if they were the reference count would be > 2, as copies were made of `A`).

At the moment unique access is testible by `r.use_count() == 2` since A and B both have access to the object when no asynchronous operations are taking place. However, I do not find this test logically sensible.

I think I should change B's container from `std::set<boost::shared_ptr<r> >` to `std:set<boost::weak_ptr<r> >` so that `r.unique()` is logically true when no asynchronous operations are taking place. Is this a sensible use of a `weak_ptr` ?

The constructor and destructor of `A` (in_process_invoker) and the register(connect) and unregister(disconect) events look as follows in my code:

```
in_process_invoker(BackEnd & b_in)
  : client_data(new ClientData()),
    b(b_in),               
    notification_object(new notification_object_()) 
{
  b.connect(client_data);  
} 

~in_process_invoker()      
{
  if(client_data.unique()) 
  {
    b.disconect(client_data);       
  }

}
```

**EDIT**

I changed my design to use raw pointers, the default constructor marks the invoker as the primary invoker and copies of it as not-primary. When the primary is destroyed it frees up the memory.

Comment: You should make it an answer, both comments are viable answers :D

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure how applicable my comments are to your setup, but I'll try to cover all options in an answer...

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure that the reference held by `B` will still be there when `A` performs the test of reference count, then why use any kind of smart pointer in `B`, why not a raw pointer? And if you don't know that `B` will still hold a reference then the current `== 2` test isn't just non-sensible, it's incorrect.

The only advantage I see of a `weak_ptr` over a raw pointer is that if you change things in future so that `A` doesn't unregister with `B`, hence the reference might dangle, then a `weak_ptr` becomes useful to tell `B` what's happened. That might not even be possible depending how `B` uses `r`: if the design relies heavily on the fact that the reference is always valid then there's no point half-assing an attempt to cover the case that it isn't.

You could stick with `shared_ptr` everywhere, though, if `A` holds the reference to `r` via a `shared_ptr` to a proxy object, while `B` holds the reference with a `shared_ptr` directly to `r`. Then make it the responsibility of the proxy object to unregister from `B`. That way, the last copy of `A` to be destroyed will destroy the proxy, and the proxy will unregister with `B` and then destroy `r`. No need for anyone to check `use_count`.

A similar option is for `B` to hold a raw pointer, and have `r` unregister itself with `B` in its destructor. It might be harder to make that thread-safe, I'm not sure.

Ideally you'd use the "right" pointer type for the ownership semantics. If `B` co-owns `r`, then it should have a `shared_ptr`, so that `r` can safely outlive `A`. If `B` doesn't own `r` then use a `weak_ptr` if `r` might not be unregistered from `B` prior to destruction (and make sure `B` does the right thing when the `weak_ptr` has expired), or a raw pointer if `B` has a guarantee from someone else to ensure the validity of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to mix smart and raw pointers. The
whole point of using smart pointers is to have a way
to manage object deallocation, and raw
pointers undermine that, since there is no way to
know whether a non-NULL raw pointer is valid or not.

Your solution using weak pointers seems sound to me
--- it clearly distinguishes owning from non-owning
references. I have made extensive use of
this approach, where some object A is owned by one
other object B, which holds it through a long-lived
shared pointer, and the same object A is also
referenced from any number of other objects C-Z
through weak pointers. See my answer to a related question: [shared_ptr: what's it used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344031/shared-ptr-whats-it-used-for/6741335#6741335)

Comment: "_It is not safe to mix smart and raw pointers._" It is unsafe to use pointers, to use `delete`, to use arithmetic (overflow has UB), it is unsafe to program in C++ in general. Java is unsafe in other ways (notably data races can give surprising results, even Sun has had bugs with data races in Java). You might want to avoid programming in general, as it is unsafe.